# How to edit/view a big log file, more than 200MB

Tags: logging, editor

I have a Java application, I have many logs. The log size is over 200 MB. How to open a big file, for example over 200 MB?

Are there some tool to handle it?

Comment: I think some hex viewers can help you. They open files in parts, not the whole content. You can search for hex viewers, it depends on your OS. Most are free.

Answer (score 1):

Any tool that doesn't try to load the entire thing into memory at once will be relatively fast. I'd question the need for an editor unless you're actually going to edit it (rather than just view it).

You can always resort to `less` or `pg` or one of the other text file paging tools, or use `grep` to only get the lines you're interested in. Even on platforms that don't have them natively (I'm looking at *you,* Windows), they can be obtained easily - see [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) for example, especially [the packages page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html).